# Tag synonym: Recruiters -> Recruitment?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

It seems the [recruiters](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recruiters) and [recruitment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recruitment) tags are being used in basically the same way, and I don't personally see the value of splitting the process of recruiting/being recruited (recruitment) and the people doing that recruitment (recruiters).

Should we make [recruiters](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recruiters) as synonym of [recruitment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recruitment)?

Answer (score 4):

There was one question tagged [recruitment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recruitment), [Is it better to invest energy in curating an online resume (LinkedIn, StackOverflow Careers) or a Word document?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-it-better-to-invest-energy-in-curating-an-online-resume-linkedin-stackoverf) that didn't really seem to fit with "recruiters", so I retagged it with a new tag [job-search](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-search).

Now that there are only two questions remaining, one which I can't comprehend what it pertains to and another relating to recruiters, I say **yes**, they should be made synonyms.

Comment: +1 I agree with these comments; merge 'em.

Comment: I've gone ahead and merged. Reminder; if in the future there IS a valid reason for these to be separate tags, the tags can be unsynomized.

Answer (score 2):

Pardon me but i bag to differ.

Recruiters should be used for questions to deal with Recruiters such as:

[The etiquette of connecting with recruiters on networking sites](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/the-etiquette-of-connecting-with-recruiters-on-networking-sites)

[Does the average candidate have any recourse when they encounter an unethical recruiter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-proper-way-to-deal-with-an-unethical-recruiter)

Where are there are others which are about *recruitment process* - such as:

[Listing LinkedIn profile as a full CV - looks lazy, or convenient for recruiters?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/listing-linkedin-profile-as-a-full-cv-looks-lazy-or-convenient-for-recruiters)

[Should I reach out for an opportunity via personal contacts or a recruiter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/should-i-reach-out-for-an-opportunity-via-personal-contacts-or-a-recruiter)

I agree that line is too thin for many - but in genuine meaning these two tags are different.

Comment: Please feel free to use [tag:job-search] for these.  I believe the words recruitment and recruiters are simply too close to have a useful distinction so I used that new tag for a question similar to the two you listed.

Comment: Dealing with recruiters is part of the recruitment process, is it not? How do I deal with recruitment with no recruiters involved? How do I deal with recruiters (in a recruiter-specific function) without recruitment being involved? Both tags seem equally valid on all four of those questions.